# Where can I find Mozilla NSPR Package?

Tags: mono, mozilla

I tried to find Mozilla NSPR through synaptic without luck. Does anyone know what is it package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name of NetScape Portable Runtime Library in Ubuntu is `libnspr4-0d`.

To install open a terminal and run the command: `sudo apt-get install libnspr4-0d`

Hope this helps.